# how to check the int range in java and limit it only 5digits

Tags: java

Please help with my assignment. Here is the question:

> Create a separate test driver class
>   called TestEmployeePayroll that will
>   test the EmployeePayroll class by
>   performing the following:
>
> Prompt the user to enter the
>   employees’ ID number, First name, Last
>   name, Pay Category and Hours worked
>   (one at a time).
>
> - The user entry for employees ID
>     number must be exactly 5 digits long.
> - The user entry for Category must only
>     be accepted if it is in the range 1
>     to 4.
> - The user entry for Hours worked
>     must only be accepted if it is the
>     range 1 to 80.

This is what I did till now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestEmployeePayRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EmployeePayRoll obj1 = new EmployeePayRoll();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Employee ID number: "+ " ");
        String EmployeeID = input.nextLine();

        //How to check the range here if int is 5 digits long or not ?

        System.out.println("Enter the first Name: "+ " ");
        String FirstName =  input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Last Name: "+ " ");
        String LastName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the Pay Category: "+ " ");
        double PayCategory = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of hours worked: "+ " ");
        double HoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is the smallest number that has 5 digits? What is the biggest number that has 5 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the length of a String and then convert it to number, *Oli Charlesworth* told you how to convert it, or you can measure the number. It depends on what you want. Is 012345 a valid ID? It's a 6 char String but it is less than the biggest 5 digits number.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost got it...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestEmployeePayRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // ... get the values, as you are doing already
        // validate input
        int employeeIdAsInteger = validateAndConvertEmployeeId(EmployeeId);
        int payCategoryAsInteger = validateAndConvertPayCategory(PayCategory);
        // ... and so on
    }

    private int validateAndConvertEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        // The user entry for employees ID number must be exactly 5 digits long.
        if (employeeId == null || employeeId.trim().length() != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("employee id must be exactly 5 digits long");
        }
        // will throw an exception if not a number...
        return Integer.parseInt(employeeId);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok I will show you the requirement I got in my assignment. I don't  mean you to do my assignment by any means. I will show you the code what I did to my best from three days. Its so frustrating I can't figure simple problem of checking the int date range and few other small stuff in putting data into getter methods. You wil get an idea what I mean when u see it...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your objectives & constraints, you could look into the Pattern class and use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for conditions like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestEmployeePayRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEmployeePayRoll obj1 = new TestEmployeePayRoll();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Employee ID number: " + " ");
        String EmployeeID = input.nextLine();

        if (EmployeeID.trim().length() != 5) {
            System.out.println("--- Enter valid Employee ID number ---");
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the first Name: " + " ");
        String FirstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Last Name: " + " ");
        String LastName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the Pay Category: " + " ");

        double PayCategory = input.nextDouble();

        Double pay = new Double(PayCategory);

        if (pay.isNaN()) {
            System.out.println("***** Enter a valid Pay Category *****");
        }
        if (!(PayCategory >= 0 && PayCategory <= 5)) {
            System.out.println(" --- PayCategory must be between 0 and 5");
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the number of hours worked: " + " ");

        double HoursWorked = input.nextDouble();

        Double hours = new Double(HoursWorked);

        if (hours.isNaN()) {
            System.out.println("--- Enter a valid hours value ----");
        } else {
            if (!(HoursWorked >= 1 && HoursWorked <= 80)) {
                System.out.println("--- Enter value between 1 and 80 ---");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help But the if statement....(pay.isNaN()) is giving error--Double cannot be deferenced :(

Comment: Can u post the exception you are getting.

Comment: I fixed it but Its not checking the paycategory is between 0 and 5 ? It is just checking the nan-not a number  ? And also if I enter the Employee ID wrong the program just stops

Comment: I am not getting exception. Value for PayCategory should be a number.

Comment: Yeah that true but Its not checking if the Pay Category is in the range between 0 and 5 or not ?

Comment: Try putting in Employee ID as 1 when you run the program. It just asks you to put the correct EmployeeID but doesn't take any more inputs

Comment: What is the actual problem or requirement u need , post in detail .

Comment: Ok I will show you the requirement I got in my assignment. I don't mean you to do my assignment by any means. I will show you the code what I did to my best from three days. Its so frustrating I can't figure simple problem of checking the int date range and few other small stuff in putting data into getter methods. You wil get an idea what I mean when u see it...Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I get your email address so that I can email it to you or buzz me on kvp.cosmo@yahoo.com please bro thanx

Comment: I sent email to your Gmail thnx